# wedge product with and without a second pair of vectors

Tags: notation, differential-forms

I am starting to study wedge products, and am stuck on notation.
The Bachman book on differential forms says 
$$
   \omega \wedge \nu ( v_1, v_2 )
$$
"gives the area of the parallelogram spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$
projected on the plane containing the vectors $\omega$ and $\nu$,
and multiplied by the parallelogram spanned by $\omega$ and $\nu$."

Other authors just write 
$$
    \omega \wedge \nu
$$ with no reference to a second pair of vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$.

In this second case, am I to assume that the second pair of vectors exist (what are they)?  If not, are there then two different types of wedge product?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the function $f_w(v) = v \cdot w$.

I can write $f_w(v)$ for some vector $v$, or I can talk about the *function* $f_w$. Both are legitimate objects of study, just as $\sin(\pi)$ and the sine function (as a function) are of interest.

The authors who write the second form are denoting a function that takes two vectors as arguments, but they're not writing the vectors -- they're talking about the function itself, rather than its value on a pair of vectors.